# getting null values in my java web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

Hi i have java web service created by jersey.If i test from postman it works properly.I integrated the api in the gui.If i test from the gui i am getting null value.I dont know why it is printing null value.I am using application/x-www-form-urlencoded in postman

My code

```
public class RESTservice {

@POST
@Path("/data")

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMsg(@FormParam("data") String JSONString) throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException, JSONException
{
    StoreIntoHDFS obj = new StoreIntoHDFS(JSONString);
    String response1 = obj.storeAddress();
    return Response.status(200).entity(response1).build();
}
}
```

my store file

```
public class StoreIntoHDFS {
public String JSONString;
public StoreIntoHDFS(String jSONString) {
    super();
    JSONString = jSONString;

}

 public String storeAddress() throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    BufferedWriter br = null;
    FileSystem hdfs = null;

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

        hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://aserver:8020"), conf);

        Path file = new Path("hdfs://aserver:8020/user/ec2-user/PropertyDetails/" + date.getTime());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(JSONString);
        byte[] byt = sb.toString().getBytes();
        FSDataOutputStream fsOutStream = hdfs.create(file);
        fsOutStream.write(byt);
        fsOutStream.close();

        obj.put("status", 1);
        obj.put("msg", "Information stored successfully");
        obj.put("data", JSONString);

        return obj.toString();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        obj.put("status", 0);
        obj.put("msg", "Could not store the address");
        obj.put("data", e.toString());

        return obj.toString();
    }

    finally {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }

        if (hdfs != null) {
            hdfs.close();

        }

    }
}
```

}

my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do send proper Content-Type? Proper HTTP method to service? Do you expect media/json in client layer? If you query that with external tool and it works, that means that problem relies on the client side.

Comment: if I test the API from postman, I am getting proper responses.But If i test from gui I will get 'null' thats it

Comment: In postman I am using application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: And how you query the service on client level? Can you post for instance Firebug screenshot and postman screenshoot ? Maybe there are some differences?

Comment: I am trying in the gui only.The gui guys told there is some problem in code only.

Comment: my doubt is how can i mention url form decoded in java code like @produces..

Comment: You can just write:  `@Produces("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Comment: I tried this.no luck.it printing same null

Comment: Please post your Firebug query dump (request).